# Depth of field WebGL

Tags: graphics, webgl, framebuffer, post-processing

I'm new to WebGL and I need to implement Depth of Field. I'm doing this by creating two framebuffers.
On the first framebuffer I render a texture (fbTexture) and a depth texture (depthTex), which are created using 3 shader programs (for different objects).
Then I create a second fragment buffer on which I do horizontal blurring and then draw this texture with the fourth progran on canvas with added vertical blur.

```
    this.frameBuffer = gl.createFramebuffer();
    this.dof_frameBuffer = gl.createFramebuffer();

    gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, this.frameBuffer);

    this.texturefb = gl.createTexture();
    gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, false);
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, this.texturefb);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texStorage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 1, gl.RGBA8, gl.drawingBufferWidth, gl.drawingBufferHeight);
    gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl.TEXTURE_2D, this.texturefb, 0);


    this.depthTex = gl.createTexture();
    gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, false);
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, this.depthTex);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texStorage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 1, gl.DEPTH_COMPONENT16, gl.drawingBufferWidth, gl.drawingBufferHeight);
    gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, gl.TEXTURE_2D, this.depthTex, 0);

    gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, this.dof_frameBuffer);

    this.dofTexture = gl.createTexture();
    gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, false);
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, this.dofTexture);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texStorage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 1, gl.RGBA8, gl.drawingBufferWidth, gl.drawingBufferHeight);
    gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl.TEXTURE_2D, this.dofTexture, 0);


    gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null);
```

So in my draw function I create a square mesh that contains positions and i set all the uniforms:

```
    this.square = gl.createVertexArray();
    gl.bindVertexArray(this.square);
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, gl.createBuffer());
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([
        -1, -1,    
         1, -1,    
         1,  1,               
         -1,  1,    
    ]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(0);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(0, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);









    let depth = gl.getUniformLocation(program.program, "uDepth");
    gl.uniform1i(depth, 5);


    gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, this.frameBuffer);
    gl.viewport(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
```

after I draw all the scene elements (to the fbTexture)

and then at the end of the function:

```
    gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE4);
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, this.texturefb);

    gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE5);
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, this.depthTex);

    gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE6);
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, this.dofTexture);

    program = this.programs.dof;
    gl.useProgram(program.program);

    let depth = gl.getUniformLocation(program.program, "uDepth");
    gl.uniform1i(depth, 5);

    gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, this.dof_frameBuffer);
    gl.clearColor(fog.fogColor[0], fog.fogColor[0], fog.fogColor[0], fog.fogColor[3]);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.drawingBufferWidth, gl.drawingBufferHeight);

    program = this.programs.dof;
    gl.useProgram(program.program);
    gl.bindVertexArray(this.quadVAO);

    gl.uniform1f(program.uniforms.uFocusDistance, this.focusDist);
    gl.uniform1f(program.uniforms.blurCoef, this.blurCoef);
    gl.uniform1f(program.uniforms.uPPM, this.ppm);
    gl.uniform2fv(program.uniforms.uDepthRange, this.depthRange);
    gl.uniform2fv(program.uniforms.uResolution, this.resolution);

    let t = gl.getUniformLocation(program.program, "uColor");

    gl.uniform1i(t, 4);
    gl.uniform2fv(program.uniforms.uTexelOffset, this.hTexelOffset);
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
    

    gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null);
    gl.clearColor(fog.fogColor[0], fog.fogColor[0], fog.fogColor[0], fog.fogColor[3]);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.drawingBufferWidth, gl.drawingBufferHeight);

    gl.uniform1f(program.uniforms.uFocusDistance, this.focusDist);
    gl.uniform1f(program.uniforms.blurCoef, this.blurCoef);
    gl.uniform1f(program.uniforms.uPPM, this.ppm);
    gl.uniform2fv(program.uniforms.uDepthRange, this.depthRange);
    gl.uniform2fv(program.uniforms.uResolution, this.resolution);


    gl.uniform1i(t, 6);
    gl.uniform2fv(program.uniforms.uTexelOffset, this.vTexelOffset);
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
```

I use texture units 0-3 for elements in the scene - this is why the depth texture has unit 4.

I tried to follow this program : https://github.com/tsherif/webgl2examples/blob/master/dof.html ,but failed since output on the canvas looks like this :
[image]

so it only shows part of the scene. I checked the program multiple times, but i can't find the problem. Does it have to do with texture units or something? And also, is there an easier way to implement depth of field? Any help would be much appreciated!!

Comment: There isn't enough code in your question to answer. Drawing at the bottom maybe your viewport settings are wrong. See [this](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-render-to-texture.html). Something in your question makes it sound like you might have a misunderstanding of texture units Texture units are just inputs to the current shader program. You set them up before each draw call then call gl.drawXXX. Before the next draw call you set them up again for whatever textures that draw call needs. See [this](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-texture-units.html)

Comment: As for depth of field you you can look at [this](https://webglsamples.org/field/field.html) maybe? [Source](https://github.com/WebGLSamples/WebGLSamples.github.io/tree/master/field)